# Filament v3 : relation Manager with hasMany and BelongsTo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-filament

I'm learning Filament but I'm stuck on the relations managers:

I have 2 tables :
"Etablissements" (=establishment in french) which have 2 colones : id and nom
"Users" which have 5 colones : id, name, mail, password, etablissement_id

i try to setup my relation manager how is write in the documentation but i didn't succed.

my code :

Model Etablissement

```
class etablissements extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'etablissements';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'etablissement_id');
    }
}
```

Model Users :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function etablissement(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Etablissement::class);
    }
}
```

UsersRelationManager.php :

```
class UsersRelationManager extends RelationManager
{
    protected static string $relationship = 'users';

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Select::make('author_id')
                    ->label('Author')
                    ->options(User::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ->searchable()
            ]);
    }

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->recordTitleAttribute('name')
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I create a new establishment, I must choose 1 (or more) users who will be connected to the establishment. A User can only be linked to 1 establishment.
But when I connect my user to the establishment, the script creates a new user instead of choosing an existing one.

I put some ref :
[edditing page for establishment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuzMM.png)

[it offers me the users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWLO7.png)

[But when i click on "create" the script create a new user instead of modify the etablissement_id of my user that i choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs2kM.png)

For infirmation, i work witth :

- laravel 10
- php 8.1
- filament v3

I try to read the docs, look other code but i find nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use Associate actions in your header actions.

Here's what you want:

```php
class UsersRelationManager extends RelationManager
{
    protected static string $relationship = 'users';

    // we need to define the inverse relationship name otherwise it will look for plural
    protected static ?string $inverseRelationship = 'etablissement';

    // nothing changed in the below method
    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Select::make('name')
                ->searchable(['name'])
            ]);
    }

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Select::make('author_id')
                    ->label('Author')
                    ->options(User::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ->searchable()
            ]);
    }

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->recordTitleAttribute('name')
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                // ...
                // It opens a dialog to select the related model
                Tables\Actions\AssociateAction::make(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                // ...
                Tables\Actions\DissociateAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    // ...
                    Tables\Actions\DissociateBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

Now, the Create button is removed, and you see the Attach button where you can search and find your related model.

[here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/relation-managers#associating-and-dissociating-records) you can read more about associating records.

Also, you need to specify the inverse relationship name. Otherwise, it will look for `etablissements` instead of `etablissement` in the User model.

Comment: According to [this](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/), his naming convention with a singular belongsTo relation and a plural hasMany relation. But [filament documentation](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/relation-managers#unconventional-inverse-relationship-names) seems to suggest otherwise. Am I missing something, or is this the documentation being unclear?